# jquery animate to min-height or auto

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery stuff here to animate a layer on click. Problem is sometimes the content may exceed the height allotted in the height setting. Is there any way to modify this to animate the layer to a minimum height or auto instead of a set px amount?

```
$(function() {
    $(".showcart").click(function(){
        $("#cart").animate({ height: "250px" }).animate({ height: "200px" }, "fast");
    });
    $(".hidecart").click(function(){
        $("#cart").animate({ height: "250px" }).animate({ height: "0px"}, "fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you can't tell it to just animate to what will fit. To do this you'll either have to already know the right size or have a way to calculate it.

If this all happens within a single function or a single plugin you may want to consider storing the value of `$(this).height()` in a variable somewhere before you expand it, hence you'll be able to put it back to where it used to be.

Otherwise one possibility might be to put a div inside the one you intend to grow/shrink and use `get $('> div', $(this)).height()` to get the height of your div that's inside it which should be the height of the content in it no matter how much you mess with the outside div's height.

Answer (score 22):

I found that you can just do this:

```
 $("#cart").animate({ 'min-height': "250px" }, 'fast');
```

Quotes are the key thing here.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a tough one, because it depends a lot on the structure of your page. If you can set the css min-height, or get the height of another element as a point of reference you could animate to that size making things a little more dynamic. There is unfortunately no auto-magic resize method in jQuery.

```
$(this).css("min-height"); //Gets min-height CSS property

// or..

$(this).height(); //Gets element height
```

Hope that helps.